# YOLO vs Inception on unique images

Tags: tensorflow, yolo

I have images of unique products that are used at my workplace. I can't imagine that the inception database already has similar items that it has been trained on.

I tried to train a model using YOLO. It was taking a very very long time. Maybe 7minutes between epochs; and I wanted to do 1000 epochs due to small data size.

I used tiny-yolov2-voc cfg/weight on 1.0 GPU. I had a video of the item but i broke it up into frames so i could annotate. I then attempted to train on the images (not video). The products are healthcare related. Basically anything that a hospital would use.

Ive also used the inception method on images I got from Google. I noticed that inception method was very fast and resulted in accurate predictions. However, i'm worried that my images are too unique for inception to work.

Which method is best to use?

If you recommend YOLO, can you please provide suggestions on how to speed up the training phase?

If you recommend inception, can you please provide an explanation why it would work on unique images? I guess i'm having trouble understanding how inception knows which item i'm trying to train on without me providing annotations.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please add details to your question like if you installed darknet or COCO and which version of YOLO you're using? It's running on CPU or GPU? You train on single images or video? Add whatever is useful. Getting an idea about the nature of your special products might be helpful too. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks David. I have now added some details. Also, i'm pretty sure its darknet. Here is the link to the github repo i used. https://github.com/thtrieu/darkflow

Answer (score 1):

Just my impression (no recommendation or even related experience)

Having a look at the [Hardware recommendations](https://pjreddie.com/darknet/hardware-guide/) related to `darknet` a assumption is that you might stock up your own hardware to get faster results.
I read about the currently three different versions of `YOLO` and expect there are lot's of GFLOPS training included if you download the recommended files, but if the models never fit to your products then for you they never might be very helpful.
I must admit I've neither been active with `YOLO` nor with `Tensorflow`, so my impression might not be helpful at all.
If you see some videos of `YOLO` you can remark that sometimes a camel is labeled with horse and the accuracy seems being bad but it depends on the threshold that is applied to the images, so the videos look amazing as it seems the recognition is done so fast but with higher accuracy the process would slow down - also depending on the trained motives.
They never hide it though, they explain on an image where a dog is labeled as cow and a horse as sheep ([Version 2](https://pjreddie.com/darknet/yolov2/)) that in combination with darknet it's getting much faster but less accurate too, so usage of darknet is an important aspect too.
The information about details seems being quite bad on the websites of `YOLO`, they present it more like you'd do with a popstar, in comparison the website of `Tensorflow` looks more academic and is informing about the mathematics behind the framework.
Concerning `Tensorflow` I don't know about the hardware-recommendations, but as you wrote your results are useful, probably they are a bit or even much less.
My impression is that `YOLO` is primary intended for real-time detection in (live-)videos and needs much training for high accuracy. So depending on your use-case it might be right but you'd to invest in hardware probably for professional usage.
This is not an opinion against `Tensorflow` but that I had to verify more and it seems taking more time to get an impression. Concerning `Tensorflow` in the moment I even can't say if it can be used for real-time-detection, how accurate it is then and if the results are then still better then those of `YOLO`.

My assumption is that concerning both solutions it's a matter of involved elements (like the decision if to include darknet for speed), configuration, training and adjustments. Probably there is always something to increase in speed and accuracy, so investing in a system for recognition won't be static process with fixed end in timeline, but a steady process.

This is just a short overview of my impressions, I've never any experience with any  recognition-software and hardly recommend that you make any decision based on my words.
Just if you want to do use any recognition software professional, especially for real-time-recognition, then you've to invest in hardware probably.

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding of your problem you need you need inception with the capability of identifying your unique images. In this circumstance you can use *transfer-learning* on the inception model. With *transfer-learning* you can still train inception your own pictures while retaining the previous knowledge of inception.

More on [transfer-learning](https://towardsdatascience.com/transfer-learning-946518f95666)